# Alternating routines sharing a mutex

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mutex, condition-variable

I have method `a` that is invoked repeatedly at some random time, which triggers method `b`, which is completely executed after some random time and is in it own thread. I want to ensure that a subsequent execution of `a` waits until `b` is completed, which is triggered by the current execution of `a`. In other words, `a` and `b` are to be executed alternatively. I tried to do this using mutex and condition variable as follows:

```
def a
  Thread.new do
    $mutex.synchronize do
      puts "a"
      b
      $cv.wait($mutex)
    end
  end
end

def b
  Thread.new do
    sleep(rand)
    $mutex.synchronize do
      puts "b"
      $cv.signal
    end
  end
end

$mutex, $cv = Mutex.new, ConditionVariable.new
loop{a; sleep(rand)}
```

In this code, `$mutex.synchronize do ... end` in method `a` ensures that `$cv.signal` (also within another `$mutex.synchronize do ... end`) in method `b` is not invoked until `$cv.wait($mutex)` sets `$cv` into listening mode for signals. This much is given in [the document](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/ConditionVariable.html).

Another function I intended to assign to `$mutex.synchronize do ... end` in method `a` is to avoid consecutive execution of method `a`. My reasoning is that `$cv.wait($mutex)` in method `a` should avoid `$mutex` from being completed and released until `$cv.signal` in method `b` is invoked, by which time `b` should be finished.

I expected that `a` and `b` are executed alternatively, thereby printing `"a"` and `"b"` alternatively. But in reality, they are not; each of `"a"` or `"b"` can be printed consecutively.

---

After that, I thought that my reasoning above may be wrong in the sense that `$mutex` is rather completed and released even if `$cv` (or `$mutex`) is in waiting mode, once `$cv.wait($mutex)` has been **called**. So I added some dummy process to `a`, changing it to:

```
def a
  Thread.new do
    $mutex.synchronize do
      puts "a"
      b
      $cv.wait($mutex)
      nil # Dummy process intended to keep `$mutex` locked until `$cv` is released
    end
  end
end
```

but that did not have effect.

---

How can this be fixed? Or, what am I wrong about this?

Comment: Will `b` eventually be called outside of `a`?

Comment: @fotanus No. It is called only from `a`. But they cannot be put together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it sounds strange, but it will be easier to use a queue to block those threads:

```
def a
  Thread.new do
    $queue.pop
    puts "a"
    b
  end
end

def b
   Thread.new do
    sleep(rand)
    puts "b"
    $queue << true
  end
end

$queue = Queue.new
$queue << true
loop{a; sleep(rand)}
```

Comment: Your methods are not in individual threads, so they are ensured to work alternately.

Comment: @sawa: Sorry, forgot to include the threads. It works either way, because queue.pop is a blocking call.

Comment: @sawa I'm trying to make it work with mutexes. There is something really fishy in ruby mutex implementation, which I never noticed (because never need before) - gave up, going to bed

Comment: I am looking into the source of Queue, and it is implemented in Ruby. It indeed uses mutex afterall.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a solution for you, but isn't the reason `a` is being called more than you expect is `wait` releases the lock on the mutex?  Otherwise `signal` could never be called.  This seems to happen "as expected" the first time, but after that, you end up having several `a` threads queued up, itching to enter the `synchronize` block, and they sneak in before a `b` thread wakes up and locks the mutex again.

If you poor-man's instrument your code at every turn, you can see it happen:

```
def a
  puts("a before thread #{Thread.current}")
  Thread.new do
    puts(" a synch0 #{Thread.current}")
    $mutex.synchronize do
      puts("  a before b #{Thread.current}")
      b
      puts("  a after b, before wait #{Thread.current}")
      $cv.wait($mutex)
      puts("  a after wait #{Thread.current}")
    end
    puts(" a synch1 #{Thread.current}")
  end
  puts("a after thread #{Thread.current}")
end

def b
  puts("b before thread #{Thread.current}")
  Thread.new do
    puts(" b before sleep #{Thread.current}")
    sleep(rand)
    puts(" b after sleep, synch0 #{Thread.current}")
    $mutex.synchronize do
      puts("  b before signal #{Thread.current}")
      $cv.signal
      puts("  b after signal #{Thread.current}")
    end
    puts(" b synch1 #{Thread.current}")
  end
  puts("b after thread #{Thread.current}")
end

$mutex, $cv = Mutex.new, ConditionVariable.new
loop{a; sleep(rand)}
```

Comment: I think you are right. I was starting to feel the same thing.